# Highcahrt time format issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dotnethighcharts, highcharts-ng

this is my yAxsis and normally displays time for column range chart

```
  yAxis: {

                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%P', this.value);
                    }
                }
```

It normally works perfect when distance is some amount .

Question : When time distance between starttime and endtime is low then yAxsis dispalys `00:00 pm` through the axsis  I also tried `%M:%P` still dispalys  `00:pm`

[here is the js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5guvaLea/)

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle example?

Comment: sorry @Ondkloss I don't have it , since it s a  big project. I just need to get some idea if you can.thakns

Comment: Well... How short is the distance between "starttime" and "endtime"? If it is less than a minute this is correct. How do you want it to look?

Comment: When the disatance is 6 hours , it is fine but when it gets 3 hours then it makes this problem.

Comment: There must be something with your data or setup. Should work fine. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3f7pdcxy/

Comment: Yes probably.Ok I am gonna go and check it once again.Thanks

Comment: I THINK THE  ISSUE RELATED AM AND PM  STARTTIME COMES 9 AM AND ENDTIME IS 8 PM THEN  IT MAKES THIS ISSUE ? DO YOU AHVE ANY SUGGESTION FOR THIS ?

Comment: It is impossible to debug if you are not able to recreate the issue. I doubt there is anything wrong with the labeling in Highcharts, so you need to find the error in your code. Either paste relevant parts of the code or your data format, then perhaps. Just setting "start 9am end 8pm" doesn't make an issue.

Comment: I just added jsfiddle .Can you take a look

Comment: Hve you tried to set [minPointLength](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.minPointLength) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sebastian .

```
minPointLength
```

did work..